# Orientdb REST API returns only 20 records

Tags: rest, orientdb

I am a newbie to OrientDB. I have seen the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601513/why-orientdb-always-return-only-20-records-only). But that question is related to the graphical view. I had doubts about the records returned by the REST API.

I was trying to run the query `http://localhost:2480/query/test-db/sql/select from V limit 100` using REST APIs.
We have a graph with 200 nodes and were trying to fetch 100 of them using the limit clause. But the result consists of only 20 records. How can I change the number of records returned by the REST API??

Comment: you should accept the answer if it resolves your question. That is how SO works :)

Answer (score 5):

The default limit is 20. For the REST API you are using, the correct syntax is:

```
http://localhost:2480/query/test-db/sql/select%20name%20from%20V/1000
```

Notice the `/1000` part ([RTFM](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-REST) :) )